# ASP.NET.Не работает метод JavaScript()

Tags: c#, asp.net

Из метода действия в контроллере вызываю метод JavaScript().Почему в браузере при обращении к методу действия он не выводится?

```
JavaScript($"alert('Запись, Id которого: {book.Id} успешно удалена из базы данных.');");
```

Код метода:

```
[HttpPost]


public ActionResult DeleteFromDb(string delete_id)   
{
        if (delete_id != null)
        {
            Book book = default(Book);

            try
            {
                book = bc.Books.Find(Int32.Parse(delete_id));
                bc.Books.Remove(book);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Redirect("/Admin/EditDb?pass=admin");
            }
            bc.SaveChanges();

            return JavaScript($"<script> alert('Запись, Id которого: {book.Id} успешно удалена из базы данных.'); </script>");
        }
        return Redirect("/Admin/EditDb?pass=admin");
}
```

Comment: Код контроллера выложи

Comment: @Alex78191 А зачем код контроллера?Код метода выложил.

Comment: было непонятно что вы делаете

Comment: @Alex78191 мне выложить код контроллера?

Comment: я спутал с методом действия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JavaScript($"alert('Запись, Id которого: {book.Id} успешно удалена из базы данных.');");
```

[Этот метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript) нужен для создания файла скрипта с `Content-Type:application/x-javascript`, который нужно вставлять с помощью тега `<script src="url">` на страницу или выполнять с помощью AJAX и eval (не рекомендуется).

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, рассказать по-подробней, или скинуть ссылку на какую-нибудь статью об этом

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541336/can-i-return-javascript-from-mvc-controller-to-view-via-ajax-request

Comment: он возвращает строку со скриптом,заложенный в тег pre, а нельзя сделать так, чтобы этот скрипт выполнялся?

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик вы прочитали, что нужно код контроллера выложить?

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик скрипт должен выполняться, но будет переход на новую страницу.

Comment: а как это исправить?

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик вы писали, что скрипт не выполняется, выполняется? Нужно использовать AJAX чтобы не было перехода на новую страницу.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @ДиванныйАналитик обновил  ответ